# Is it possible to hide a read only section entirely in popup but display it in details?

Tags: custom-object, read-only, pageblocksection, detail-page, popup-window

We have a custom object and in that object's layout, there is a section called 'Billing Information'. All of the 8 fields in that section are read-only. Is it possible to hide the section entirely in the new record creation popup but show the section in the record detail tab? The values will be populated by API from the backend. It does not look good for a user when the new popup opens with only labels without any input fields for users using profile other than System Administrator.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer provided in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/322158/how-to-show-a-specific-field-only-on-record-detail-page-hide-in-new-pop-up-page/322160#322160

Comment: @maniaccoder thanks, it seems to be working, however, is there any way to create two record types with the same name. In this solution, we are asking a user to choose a record type name x but showing y after saving the record type.

Comment: @adnam: You can create two record types with same name but different API names.
However, don't do that as it will cause confusion for users and admins.
You can also try out the answer provided by Ganesh, but that also comes with few trade-offs and can be done only in Lightning.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

1. Create Page Layout without those readonly fields.
2. Create a 'Action' (of type - Update a record) from 'Buttons, Links and Actions' section of Object. Add required read-only fields there. And drag and drop it on Record Page just below Page Layout.
3. You could also use Dynamic Forms but it's Non-GA Preview, desktop only at the moment.